# Resource id is not getting generated for the EditText widget in my android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

In fragemnet_crime.xml i have code like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"  >

  <EditText android:id="@+id/crime_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/crime_title_hint"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

In the above code i am creating a test area widget and i have given id ="@+id/crime_title"
so in R.java file an automatic resource id should be generated for crime_title but there is no field created for crime_title so in CrimeFragment.java file  when i try to retrive resource as below,it is telling crime_title cannot be resolved

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, parent, false);

mTitleField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
    }
```

Comment: Clean your project then try again.

Comment: Try cleaning your project. To clean, select your project, go to the 'Project' tab and hit 'Clean'.

Comment: yes after cleaning it generated the resource id thanku :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you use the ID, build the project. 
So just comment out the declaration line,
 `mTitleField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);`
After that, just build, uncomment, and then build again.

Answer (score 0):

One of the following solutiins may work for you :

1).  It could be the case , that there is some error in your one of the resource files , like in string.xml or in any other layout file. So, if a red mark is visible on any such file , you may just navigate to that file  , and rectify the error , which may have stopped the automatic creation of id for your text file.

2). You may check the option Build Automatically under Project Menu of top Menu Bar of Eclipse.

3). If this does not work , you may just clean and build your project .

4). If all of the above fails , just restart your Eclipse IDE, if need be .

Answer (score 0):

after cleaning the project it generated the resource id thanku :)